# Using boost library on Mac os and its location

Tags: macos, boost, location

I got a mac for the first time. I am not familiar at all with it.I installed boost on it.I am not sure whether it was successfull or not but when I tried reinstalling it said already installed.which I assume means it was indeed successfully installed.

I used brew to install boost. My problem is that I dont know where it got installed,in which folder,I cannot seem to find the path. I open file explorer.I cant seem to see all the files and folders like in windows.

Then again I would like to use it to write code.In univ we just type in emacs and g++ compiler and it works. Id like to know the setting that I need to make in order to use it this way.

Last but not least,it would be greatif you guys cud tell me how I can link it to Xcode.Id like to use an ide to use Boost.I know that most of the questions

Thank you